# Docker File does not exist:.. ,on Ubuntu

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I have an R plumber server, that i want to run using a docker container, and i have this configuration so far in my `dockerfile`

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.0

#update OS and install linux libraries needed to run plumber
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
      libssl-dev \
      libcurl4-gnutls-dev

#load in dependencies from 00_Libraries.R file
RUN R -e "install.packages('plumber')"

#Copy all files from current directory
COPY / / 

#Expose port :80 for traffic
EXPOSE 80

#when the container starts, start the runscript.R script
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "runscript.R"]
```

in my runscript.R file, i have my server configuration like this:

```
pr <- plumber::plumb("/home/kristoffer/Desktop/plumber-api/rfiles/plumber.R")$run(port=8000)
```

whenever i try to run the docker image, i get this error:

```
 File does not exist: /home/kristoffer/Desktop/plumber-api/rfiles/plumber.R
Execution halted
```

i have ensured, that all the necessary files are located in the right directory.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
i included an image of all the files i have in my directory, to ensure, that the dockerfile is in the same directory as my other files

Comment: @LinPy unfortunately it still can't find the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are copying everything under `/` change your copy command to:

```
COPY . .
```

and make sure that `Dockerfile` is in the same directory.

beside this :

```
plumber::plumb("/home/kristoffer/Desktop/plumber-api/rfiles/plumber.R")
```

will also not work since the path is not in your container change it to :

```
plumber::plumb("plumber.R")
```

if this file is in the same directory